# Prometheus global vs local limit?

Tags: prometheus

I am currently running Prometheus which writes metrics to an endpoint.

I am experiencing 429 Out of Memory issues, and seeing the following error message:

```
server returned HTTP status 429 Too Many Requests: per-metric series limit (local limit: 0 global limit: 20000 actual local limit: 12000
```

I believe this is due to the local limit being exceeded.  Where is the local limit set?

I've tried checking the Prometheus documentation, and the Prometheus Helm Chart, however, neither have a reference to how the local limit is set, and how I would go about increasing this.

Where is the local limit determined?

Is it possible to increase this somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be reported by Prometheus, As I can find, it is probably that you are using [Cortex](https://github.com/cortexproject/cortex) for long term storage, and it's reported here:

https://github.com/cortexproject/cortex/blob/ff0d52e6d2a3b1be11c4111604fe5f79c892c967/pkg/ingester/limiter.go#L13

And it could be configurated by configuration file here https://cortexmetrics.io/docs/configuration/configuration-file/, org using CLI `-ingester.max-global-series-per-metric`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check your job configuration and the value you have for `sample_limit`.
You can find the documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config)

If you have more sample than the limit, then the entire **scrape** will be skipped.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, currently I do not have the sample_limit set, so according to the documentation, this should be 0 by default meaning no limit.